# How to not color the last column in html table

Tags: css

i have every even row in my html table coloured grey. I do not want this  styling on the last column. The last column with the button should be white. Any idea how to get this to work?

```
export const StyledTable = styled.table`
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    font-size: 15px;
`;

export const TR = styled.tr`
    :nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #e5eaee;
      }
`;

export const TH = styled.th`
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #e5eaee;

`;

export const TD = styled.td`
    padding: 1rem;
`;

export const TBody = styled.tbody``;
export const THead = styled.thead`
`;
```

[image]

Comment: I have changed to CSS. Examples above.

Answer (score 2):

Use `:last-child` selector

Refer this : https://www.techonthenet.com/css/selectors/last_child.php